# Can I turn a type into JSON?

Tags: typescript

I want to convert a type (and its subtypes) into JSON during compile time, so I can easily validate properties exist without knowing the actual type. The value of the type properties would be the actual type, e.g. string, number, nested object.

For example:

```
type B {
  propX: string
}

type A {
   prop1: string
   prop2: B
}

const jsonOfTypeA = ....somehow

class MyManagerClassForTypeA {
    doSumat(prop: string, action: (val: any) => void) {
       validateProperty(jsonOfTypeA, prop); // very easy in json with libraries
    }
}
```

Expected jsonOfTypeA:

```
{
   "prop1": "string", 
   "prop2": { "propX": "string" } 
}
```

I'm asking for an automated way, not to manually write the JSON every model change.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this at build time using only Typescript meta-programming. You could try to use an existing package like [typescript-json-schema](https://github.com/YousefED/typescript-json-schema) or [ts-json-schema-generator](https://github.com/vega/ts-json-schema-generator). Otherwise, if those solutions do not fit your needs or they are too complex, you could use the [Compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) to read your types and generate JSON files.